# Easiest way to make C# not instantiate a class unless inherit?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

What is the easiest way to make C# not instantiate a class unless inherit?

Sounds weird but i dont want to explain the why. I have a base class and two class that inherit it. I want to use the derived class only and not the base. The derive class does not have any extra functions. Whats the easiest way to NOT allow me to write new BaseClass(); so i dont accidentally use it? I do have functions that operate on the base class and not the derived.

Comment: I love questions where a person describes an existing feature to the letter (in this case Abstract classes).  They are such neat and tidy questions with such clear answers, they satisfy me greatly.

Comment: turns out someone downvoted me too. Weird.

Comment: @acidzombie24, I'm guessing because you accepted an unpopular answer when there were answers with > 20 upvotes that you ignored.

Comment: Whats the big deal? I +1 the 20 votes both answers are the same. Use the abstract keyword.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Make the class an `abstract` base class.

```
abstract class Person { }

class Programmer : Person { }

var person = new Person();          // compile time error
var programmer = new Programmer();  // ok
```

Comment: You can't even see the class name on the intellisense list when trying to instantiate it which is awesome for awareness :)

Answer (score 7):

Set the class to abstract:

```
public abstract BaseClass
{



}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Can the base class be Abstract?  That would do it.

Answer (score 5):

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

instead of the normal:

`"public Class MyClass"`

make it

```
"public abstract Class MyClass"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the constructor of `BaseClass` protected:

```
public class BaseClass {

   protected BaseClass()
   {
      // DO SOMETHING
   }

}


public class Derived : BaseClass {

   public Derived() {}
}
```

Comment: Only if he can't make the base class abstract for some weird reason.

Comment: There are better solutions above.

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe your need, making your class `abstract` is the way to go. It will
stop you from instantiating the base class and will allow you to call the functions on
it. This will also allow you to mark functions and properties as abstract and 
force the inherited classes to implement them.

If you had no need to share code, an interface would be a nice option. It allows you to
implement it in a way very similar to an abstarct class and casting your 
implementations into it.

Hope this adds some value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a protected constructor for Base Class